# Need help identifying effect used on a picture

Tags: effects, pixel, image-editing

I'm not a graphics designer, but I need some help with identifying the "effect" used on a picture. The picture I'm revering to is [this one](http://goltermann.design/wp-content/themes/goltermann/images/profile_build_jg.png).

[image]

If anyone could help me naming the effect and tell me if there are any online sites that can recreate that effect with another photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply "pixelation"
(AKA "Mosaic")

Take a look at this tutorial:
https://blog.123rf.com/create-3-easy-pixelation-effects-in-photoshop/

Comment: Also known as "Mosaic"